# rownum in mariaDB not working

Tags: sql, mariadb

LIMIT is working properly but ROWNUM is not working. Here is my code-
"SELECT article_ref FROM article_write ROWNUM<=3" is not working in MariaDB.
Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<= 3' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

`rownum` is a non standard pseudocolumn that exists in Oracle's database. MariaDB just doesn't support this syntax, but as you've noticed, you can use a `limit` clause to get the same sort of result.

Comment: actually, I want 1-10 result from database, then on button click next 11-20 result and so on ..
what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

For pagination, the usual technique is

```
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

(to get the 3rd page of 10 items, for example.)

However, there are problems with doing such, and they are the same problems as with `ROWNUM`.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) for a discussion of a more efficient, less buggy, way of doing pagination.